# Adding some extra info in uname -v output string in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, unix, linux-kernel, uname

On my Linux machine when i run

```
uname -v
```

it gives me

```
#83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:12:07 UTC 2012
```

---

Now i am building my custom kernel and i need to show some flag/text info about build in this string ..

i want something like
if some config are on then add `BUILD-XYZ` in that string

```
   #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:12:07 UTC 2012 BUILD-XYZ
```

if not then add `BUILD-ABC` in that.

```
  #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:12:07 UTC 2012 BUILD-ABC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable CONFIG_LOCALVERSION (inside your kernel .config file) let you set a custom string that will be appended to the kernel release number, thus shown when using 'uname'.

Is that what you want?

Comment: oh yes this is what i have finally did..!!

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do this using `GNU awk`, here's one:

```
uname -v | awk '{ printf (/some config/) ? $0" BUILD-XYZ\n" : $0" BUILD-ABC\n" }'
```

Comment: i want to do this in kernel code. so when any user do uname-v it has resulting string